# How to change html's <p> inner text from PHP?

Tags: php, html, json

I'm trying to change a HTML element's inner text from PHP.. is this even possible? I am building a chat application for my website, (live chat) and I need to constantly update the chat by querying to a database, but I'm stuck on getting the element and changing its inner text from HTML from PHP. Thanks in advance.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['iChat'])){
    $db_address = 'localhost';
    $db_username = 'root';
    $db_password = '';
    $db_name = 'chat';
    $connection = mysqli_connect($db_address, $db_username, $db_password, $db_name);
    $message = $_POST['iChat'];
    $personaname = $_COOKIE['personaname'];

    if ($message != '' && $personaname != ''){
        $query = "INSERT INTO chat VALUES (null, '{$personaname}', '{$message}')";
    mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    }
}

function get(){
    $db_address = 'localhost';
    $db_username = 'root';
    $db_password = '';
    $db_name = 'chat';
    $connection = mysqli_connect($db_address, $db_username, $db_password,     $db_name);
    $query = "SELECT `sender`, `message` FROM chat";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    >>>> GET ELEMENT HERE <<<<<<

    return json_encode($result);
}
?>
```

Comment: I hope you're not actually using root for database access. Anyway, what I think you're looking for is jquery. Make an ajax request to get any new records and then append a new `<p>` tag for each record returned.

Comment: I'm a newbie coder... I don't quite understand. Could you please include some code? :D

Comment: That's a lot of code to include. Go look up jquery and ajax requests. It allows you to update only part of a page. When you get your database results from the ajax call, generate a `<p>` tag with the relevant content and append it to the HTML on your page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change content inside any element or at any moment or location on your website the easiest and probably best way would be an Ajax request.

With ajax requests you basically can send a post or get to your server to any given URL.

You can also pass data (variables/object). This way you can send any user generated data to your server and do something with it. (input fields for instance).

After the request has been made you have 3 callbacks: `success`, `complete`, `error`.

The complete is always fired no matter what after either the success or error callback. In the success callback you can return the `result` of your request (the value you return from your php file).

In the `error` callback you can notify the user that something went wrong, when for instance the request responded with bad request or bad gateway or time outs, 404/503 etc.

More info can be found here including some other usefull functions):
http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/

Example code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $.ajax({
        url: '?act=process',
        type: 'post',
        data: {
            id: $id,
            name:$name,
            description:$description
        },
        success: function (result) {
            $('.alert-success').show();
            console.log('Yay it worked');
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            $('.alert-danger').show();
            console.log('Something went wrong');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are looking for Ajax

1. You may have a trigger button
2. Click the button, start ajax request (For example: Using [jQuery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/))
   request your database data which return by your PHP code.
3. If the request is success, put the returning data into HTML element.

   ```
   document.getElementById("ElementID").innerHTML = "Data return by PHP!";
   ```

Comment: The problem is I need it Without a  trigger button, I want it to execute from the start continually...

Comment: OK, then make a timer and request continually.Without keep click the button. Using JavaScript function `setInterval ` is the most easiest way to implement.
By the way, there is a better way for Live Chat, check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket (HTML5) , this may help you.